# WordPress hosting posts on one domain and pages on a different domain

Tags: wordpress

What I want to do is have a seamless website using two domains. One domain for the homepage and internal pages, contact etc. One domain strictly for posts. Such as

```
http://wp-pages.c0m (for home/pages)
http://wp-posts.c0m (Only for posts)
```

My permalink structure is like this for a post:

```
http://wp-posts.c0m/this-is-some-post/
And like this for a page:
http://wp-pages.c0m/this-is-some-page/
```

Basically identical when it comes to permalinks. But I'd like to host pages on http://wp-pages.c0m and posts on http://wp-posts.c0m

I'm looking for the most efficient seamless way to do this with two different servers, domain resolving to a different IP for my testing purposes. Ideally creating posts and pages from http://wp-pages.c0m and it pushing the posts to http://wp-posts.c0m while retaining the pages being created.

There isn't a single reason for doing this it's a multitude of reasons such as for seo testing purposes etc. I'm not here to go back and forth questioning why this would be needed or why someone would want to do this.

A very specific and even technical answer would be appreciated, I'm comfortable around basic server setup.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, without having two seperate Wordpress installations on said different subdomains.

UPDATE: Or, thinking about it you might be able to achieve something like this using Wordpress Multisite (https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

You then may be able to use subdomains to have what are essentially separate sites, but link them together. E.g.

```
blog.domain.com - for your blog posts
page.domain.com - for your pages
```

(I don't fully know how Multisite works, but I believe it allows you to control content for multiple sites within one WP Admin interface).

This could be a viable option.

Comment: I'm open  to having two totally different wordpress installations not sure what you mean about different subdomains though. Can you please elaborate for me. Thanks Lee

Comment: Maybe I read it wrong, but are you using the same domain name, or completely different ones? Like are you looking for something like (example) blog.domain.com and pages.domain.com, or blogdomain.com and pagedomain.com? It may not really make any difference to the answer, but from my own opinion, keep it on one domain. You may be able to use Wordpress Multisite then.

Comment: updated the question slightly so that it's easier to read/understand. Basically I want two different instances on two different servers. Currently all the pages and posts are mixed together (30,000) posts are mixed up with a few hundred pages. I'd like to host the posts on wp-posts.com and the pages on wp-pages.com linking from the pages site to the secondary site which hosts the posts. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You'll be looking at completely separate Wordpress installations for each site then, there's no way to link up Wordpress sites that are completely different domain names.